# How to format xAxis labels iOS charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

Im implementing a barchart and I've managed to assign the data and labels. However, when i load the barchart, it only shows 3/7 of my labels and I'm not sure why.

the labels show up when i interact with the chart but they go glitchy.

I'm sorry if i haven't explained myself well but i have uploaded a .gif showing my problem.

I really need some help with the formatting of the labels on the xAxis. it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[gif of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Da9U.gif)

Answer (score 0):

i think you have used this library(https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) ... i have set x-Axis using delegate method of chart

```
func ChartView()
{  
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom
    xAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
    xAxis.labelCount = ITEM_COUNT
    xAxis.granularity = 1.0
    xAxis.valueFormatter = self

    self.updateChartData()
}

func updateChartData()
{
    self.chartView.data = nil
    self.setChartData()
}


func generateLineData() -> LineChartData
{

    let d = LineChartData()
    let entries = NSMutableArray()
    var weightstr = String()
    var datestr = String()
entries.addObject(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: ( Double(dic[setvalue]as! String)!)))
let set = LineChartDataSet(values: entries  as? [ChartDataEntry]  , label: "X-title")
    set.setColor(colorWithHexString("#FE1643"))
    set.lineWidth = 2.5
    set.setCircleColor( UIColor.whiteColor())
    set.circleHoleColor = NSUIColor.greenColor()
    set.circleRadius = 5.0
    set.circleHoleRadius = 2.5
    set.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
    set.mode = .HorizontalBezier
    set.valueTextColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    set.drawValuesEnabled = true
    set.valueFont = UIFont(name: "Exo-Regular", size: FOntSIZE(10.0))!
    set.axisDependency = .Left
    d.addDataSet(set)
    return d
}

func setChartData()
    {
        let data = CombinedChartData()
        data.lineData = self.generateLineData()
        self.chartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(months.count)-1
        self.chartView.data = data
    }

func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)
    {
        print("chartValueSelected")
    }

func chartValueNothingSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase)
{
    print("chartValueNothingSelected")
} 

func stringForValue(value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String
{
    return months[Int(round(value)) % months.count] as! String
}
```

Comment: i tried using the `stringForValue` method but it gave me the same result as before

Comment: I would debug the value which is being passed to stringForValue(). In my experience, the Charts library will "choose" on its own which values to request formatting for. So, if your chart has x values 1,2,3,4,5 you can put in  a simple print(value) in your stringForValue() to verify formatting is being requested for all these values.

Comment: @Alex i tested the `print(value)` method and it printed `0, 1.0, 2.0 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0` 

think ive got it wrong because my labels array is `let labels : [String] = "m", "t", "w", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"`